# Ajax call to update values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dynamic

I am trying to implement a JS that updates an otherwise static HTML table in a set interval without any sort of websockets etc. just using ajax calls. The page is regularly updated with new data on the source server and I want the HTML, once open in the users browser, to load the new values and replace them dynamically.

My solution is matching the user HTML's id-tags with it's updated pairs in the new version on the server and inserting them using the ajax load function.

```
  function updateVals () {
   for (var i = 0; i < (idList.length); i++) {
    $('#' + idList[i]).load('SamebutUpdated.html #' + idList[i])
   }
  }
```

Now, my problem is that when I try to update the source HTML's values on a simulated live server (VSC) while the user's HTML is open, the user's HTML jumps back to it's original data values before reloading the new ones and I'd like for it not to do that but instead keep the previously loaded ones and then replace them yet again.

Hope this is clear and cohesive enough.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Could you demonstrate that behaviour in a jsfiddle? I am not sure what you mean by "while the user's html is open"

Comment: I'll try to set one up but it might take a while since I just started with JS. What I meant by that is that the user opens the page by typing in the url. And then it's supposed to update itself by loading the values from it's (by now) possibly updated self on the server.